# perl - help removing unwanted characters within split

Tags: perl

I've got a simple perl script that I need help tweaking. I was using split to separate the key and value. I almost got what I want but I want to remove the surrounding parentheses found in the input file. Also, could is there a way to sort (make it an option) on the number values? Thanks for your help.

Ex. Input file

```
(hlu,1)
(kcq,4)
(ob2,1)
```

Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $str = '';

open FILE;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($k, $v) = split /,/;
    $str .= "$k:$v\n"
}
close FILE;
print "$str";
```

Results:

```
(hlu:1)
(kcq:4)
(ob2:1)
```

Want to see:

```
hlu:1
ob2:1
kcq:4
```

Comment: As written, it doesn't seem like you need the `open FILE` / `close FILE` - just use `while(<>)` directly. Or use `while(<FILE>)`, but not both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost identical to [Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221502/perl-help-removing-unwanted-characters-within-split/6221573#6221573), except I used a single `m//` instead of `split()` -- reads simpler IMO

Also, not sure why you have `open FILE` / `close FILE` if you're using [`while(<>)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators)... I got rid of 'em.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @items = ();
# read input from stdin/@ARGV
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    m/\((.*),(.*)\)/;
    push @items, [$1, $2];
}
# sort
@items = sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @items;

foreach(@items)
{
    my ($k, $v) = @$_;
    print "$k:$v\n";
}
```

Comment: Or simply: `push @items, [ m/\((.*),(.*)\)/ ];` you don't even need to chomp it, unless you're using the `s` flag--and needing a close-paren.

Comment: @Axeman: Good one! I didn't know about that behavior of `m//` in list context.

Answer (score 4):

Change your loop to:

```
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/[()]//g;
    my ($k, $v) = split /,/, $line;
    $str .= "$k:$v\n"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all `()` symbols as mentioned by [CanSpice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221502/perl-help-removing-unwanted-characters-within-split/6221525#6221525). Or just remove starting/ending brackets:

```
$line =~ s/^\(|\)$//g; ## escaping () symbols with \
```

To sort your data you'll need to put it in array first, then sort array:

```
my @data_lines;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    s/^\(|\)$//g;
    push(@data_lines, [ split /,/ ]); ## save columns in array
}
## sort data numerically by second column
@data_lines = sort {$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]} @data_lines;
## output result
for my $row (@data_lines) {
    my ($k, $v) = @$row; ## put values into variables for convenience
    print "$k:$v\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
print "$_\n" for                  # 5
    map join(':', @$_),           # 4
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }  # 3
    map [ /(\w+),(\d+)/ ],        # 2
    <>                            # 1
;
```

You can interpret such pipelines in reverse order:

1. Read the input lines.
2. Use a regex to capture the items we care about. Package those items (`$1` and `$2`) in an array ref.
3. Sort those array refs numerically using element `[1]`.
4. Convert the little arrays to colon-separated strings.
5. Print 'em.